# How to build windows-SDK public bata 0.1?

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I read README, open DJIWindowsSDKSample.sln and try built.
I am also getting the errors like this.

> "the type of namespace name `DJI` could not be found."   "the type of
>   namespace name `SDKRegistrationState` could not be found."

...

I try add reference `DJIWindowsSDK.dll`, these errors was solved.
But getting new errors like this.

> "Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'Windows-SDK-master\Sample
>   Code\Debug\DJIVideoParser\DJIVideoParser.winmd'"

...

I can't find "DJIVideoParser.winmd".
why?
Perhaps public bata still can not be done easily?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the following settings to fix the issue:

1. Right click the DJIVideoParser and select Properties to open the property page
   [image]
2. Change the targeted platform version to match the machine's version, in my case it's 10.0.17134.0
   [image]
3. Then regenerate the DJIVideoParser
4. Run the Sample code

PS: Sorry it's in Chinese, but you get the points:)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Oliver's comment didn't help at first. Then I updated my VS2071 to the latest version (15.9) and now it compiles.